# Is there a recent update on the mysterious M82 radio source reported in 2010?

Tags: galaxy, radio-astronomy, quasars

The Wikipedia page on the ["Cigar Galaxy" (M82)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_82) has the following summary about an "unknown object":

> In April 2010, radio astronomers working at the Jodrell Bank
>   Observatory of the University of Manchester in the UK reported an
>   object in M82 that had started sending out radio waves, and whose
>   emission did not look like anything seen anywhere in the universe
>   before.

A subsequent article in *New Scientist* dated [13 December 2010](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn18775-mysterious-radio-waves-emitted-from-nearby-galaxy/) offers the following update:

> The object is still a puzzle, says co-discoverer Tom Muxlow. “It was
>   still there the last time we looked, so its lifetime is now well over
>   a year,” he says. “We are continuing to monitor this object.”

I can find a number of other references to this unknown object, but nothing more recent than 2010. The articles suggest it could perhaps be a new type of [microquasar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microquasar), since it shares some similarities; however, it doesn't have the high X-ray output that known microquasars exhibit.

Has the mystery been solved, or is this still an area of active research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SIMBAD page for the source in question: [EQ J095552.5+694045.4](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=EQ%20J095552.5%2B694045.4&submit=submit%20id)

From the list of references, the most relevant ones to this question appear to be as follows:

- [Joseph et al. (2011)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011MNRAS.415L..59J/abstract) suggest that the object could be a microquasar similar to [SS 433](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_433), which has a high radio to X-ray luminosity ratio.
- [Gendre et al. (2013)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013MNRAS.431.1107G/abstract) argue against a supernova interpretation for the source:

  > Muxlow et al. (2010) suggested that this
  >   object might either be due to accretion around a massive collapsed
  >   object or be a faint and unusual supernova (Joseph, Maccarone &
  >   Fender 2010). In the latter case, we would expect the flux density
  >   to steadily decrease over time, as the source would be too young to
  >   have reached the remnant phase. However, in the observations presented here, it shows 
  >   a flux density at 5 GHz of ∼0.90 mJy, which
  >   does not seem to vary significantly over the period 2009 May–2010.
  >   The supernova hypothesis is thus unlikely.
- [Mattila et al. (2013)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013MNRAS.431.2050M/abstract) state that the nature of the source is still unclear but they favour the microquasar interpretation:

  > The nature of the 43.78+59.3 transient remains elusive, and on
  >   the basis of the limited data available, we regard an extremely bright
  >   extragalactic microquasar as the most plausible scenario, perhaps
  >   from a high-mass X-ray binary such as LS 5039 (Clark et al. 2001),
  >   but with a high ratio of radio to X-ray flux. A bright extragalactic microquasar was 
  >   proposed as the most likely explanation by
  >   Muxlow et al. (2010) and Joseph et al. (2011). We concur with that
  >   conclusion although it would mean that the NIR luminosity is a
  >   factor of about 30 higher than Galactic microquasars.
- [Varenius et al. (2015)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015A%26A...574A.114V/abstract) note that the source was not detected with [LOFAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-Frequency_Array_(LOFAR)).

So from these, the nature of the source hasn't yet been conclusively shown, though the most plausible scenario is that it is a somewhat extreme example of a microquasar.

Comment: I guess it could be some kind of maser process, as described in [Cyclotron Maser Emission from Blazar Jets?](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005ApJ...625...51B/abstract), which says "Less massive relativistic jet sources, such as microquasars, are even better candidates for producing cyclotron maser emission, primarily in the infrared and optical bands."